# Finding a binary for a package in Linux

Tags: r

I am finishing a package, however I seem not to find a way to make the package locate a binary in the system, please note the code below:

```
    find_nim <- function(message=TRUE) {
  nimexe <- ""
  if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
      nimexe <- try(system2("which", "nim", stdout=TRUE))
      if (message) message("Nim found at ", nimexe)
  } else {
    message("Unrecognized operating system.")
  }
#  if (nimexe=="") message("nim executable not found.\n Specify the location of your nim executable.")
  return(nimexe)
}
```

This returns at installation of the package:

```
Warning in system2("which", "nim", stdout = TRUE) :
  running command ''which' nim' had status 1
Nim found at 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘nimrmarkdown’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'nimrmarkdown', details:
  call: if (nimexe != "") {
  error: argument is of length zero
```

The same code works locally in R.

- What is the proper way of checking for a binary on the system in package development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R itself has `Sys.which()` you could use:

```
R> Sys.which("emacs")
           emacs 
"/usr/bin/emacs" 
R> Sys.which("does_not_exist")
does_not_exist 
            "" 
R>
```

The *Writing R Extensions* manual mentions it too:

```
 Usage of external commands should always be conditional on a test
 for existence (perhaps using 'Sys.which'), as well as declared in
 the 'SystemRequirements' field.
```

and

```
 example in some locales.  (Use e.g. 'capabilities()' or
 'nzchar(Sys.which("someprogram"))' to test for features needed in
 the examples wherever possible, and you can also use 'try()' or
```