# test existence of executable file on path when directory is unknown

Tags: r, path, file-exists

I want to test for the existence of an executable file on the user's path. I don't know exactly where it may be installed; I just want to know whether it's on the path, such that it can be run from any directory. In Linux, I might use `locate` for this task; in Windows, I would use `where`. What is the cross-platform R equivalent?

A slow way of sort-of doing the job is to use `system2()`. Here is an example:

```
if (system2('pdflatex') == 127) print("pdflatex could not be executed")
```

My main objection to this procedure is that it's slow. To determine whether the executable is on the path and usable, `system2` actually tries to run the executable. Is there a faster way?

Comment: maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59447614/finding-a-binary-for-a-package-in-linux/59448342#59448342

Comment: You should not use `locate` to determine if an executable is present, that will list all files (that match). Instead, unix's `which` is the way to go to test if something is in the current `PATH`. R has the `Sys.which` function which effectively does the same thing (cross-platform, no less).

Comment: `if (!nzchar(Sys.which("pdflatex"))) stop("'pdflatex' could not be found")`